# Linq to Entities (EF): How to get the value of a FK without doing the join

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using the Linq to Entities. I've got my main table, Employee setup with a field named vendorID. Vendor ID is a foreign key into the Vendors table.

As it is right now, the Employee object does not directly expose the vendorID. Instead, I can only access it this way:

```
var employee = (from e in context.Employees.Include("tbl_vendors")
               where e.employeeID = 1
               select e).FirstOrDefault();

//this gets the vendor ID
int vendorID = employee.tbl_vendors.vendorID;
```

That is just fine and dandy, but it is extra work on the database because it is forcing a join where none is needed. Is there a way to get that key value without being forced to do a join to the tbl_vendors table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the foreign key via the entity reference.

```
Employee employee = context.Employees.Single(e => e.employeeID == 1);

Int32 vendorID = (Int32)employee.tbl_vendorsReference.EntityKey.
   EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
```

See MSDN for reference on the [EntityReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb154700(loband).aspx) and [EntityKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.entitykey.aspx) classes.

Comment: So is there no way to reference it by name instead of by the index location of the key? It seems dangerous to use the index since it could potentially be changed if a new key is added to the table.

Comment: It's not the index location of the key, it's the index location of the column within the key - it is taking into account the possibility of composite keys

Comment: You could search through the EntityKey.EntityKeyValues and inspect the EntityKeyMember.Key property holding the key name to find the key value you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Actually this is very simple you basically do this:

```
var tblVendorID = (from e in context.Employees
                  select e.tbl_vendors.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Even though this looks like you are doing a join L2E will optimize out the join.

Which you can confirm with code like this:

```
var results = from e in ctx.Employees
              select e.tbl_vendors.ID;

var query = results as ObjectQuery<int>;
string sql = query.ToTraceString();
```

Hope this helps
Alex (Microsoft).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your object names here but you can grab the key from the entity key property without going to the database something like this:

```
var employee = (from e in context.Employees
               where e.employeeID = 1
               select e).FirstOrDefault();

//this gets the vendor ID
int vendorID = (int)employee.tbl_vendorsReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
```